# How to Inject a parameter to constructor using unity

Tags: vb.net, unity-container, asp.net-web-api

Hi I am using unity in WebAPI 1.0 and registered it under Global.asax.vb file as below

```
Dim container As IUnityContainer = New UnityContainer()
```

`container.RegisterType(Of Car)(New InjectionConstructor(GetType(Integer)))`

Now how do i pass integer value which is passed by the client application into car type using

```
Public Sub New(ByVal intUserId As Int32)
    objCar = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(Of car)()     

End Sub
```

Can't find anything to use (ParameterOverride("intUserId", intUserId) within DependencyResolver

Comment: your type registration is wrong as well.

Comment: Using Interface is that necessary?

Comment: interface or an abstract class. How else it would be considered as dependency?

Answer (score 1):

It is very similar as registering unity container with ASP.NET MVC. Though web api has a different execution pipe line. Follow these steps.

NB: I have converted this code from C# to VB using a converter. So I hope it is syntactically correct. Though it is accurate in c#.

1) Implement *IDependencyResolver* (Make sure you are resolving correct namespace here. *IDependencyResolver* should come from *System.Web.Http.Dependencies*. Make note of Imported namespaces.

```
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Web
Imports Microsoft.Practices.Unity
Imports System.Web.Http.Dependencies

Namespace YourNamespace.Framework
    Public Class UnityApiDependencyResolver
        Implements IDependencyResolver

        Private _container As IUnityContainer = Nothing

        Public Sub New(container As IUnityContainer)
            Me._container = container
        End Sub

        Public Function GetService(serviceType As Type) As Object
            Try
                Return _container.Resolve(serviceType)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function

        Public Function GetServices(serviceType As Type) As IEnumerable(Of Object)
            Try
                Return _container.ResolveAll(serviceType)
            Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception

                Return Nothing
            End Try
        End Function

        Public Function BeginScope() As IDependencyScope
            Return Me
        End Function

        Public Sub Dispose()
            '
        End Sub
    End Class
End Namespace

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```

2) Configure your container either thgough config or through code.

3) Register your container in Global.asax.vb file

```
Dim container = New UnityContainer()
Dim section As UnityConfigurationSection = TryCast(ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unity"), UnityConfigurationSection)

section.Configure(container, "UnitySection")

'api dependency resolver
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = New UnityApiDependencyResolver(container)

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```

Thats it. 
Now you can declare your dependency in any of your API controller and it will be injected by Unity

```
Public Sub New(repositoryFactory As IRepositoryFactory, serviceFactory As IServiceFactory)
    Me.repositoryFactory = repositoryFactory
    Me.serviceFactory = serviceFactory
End Sub

'=======================================================
'Service provided by Telerik (www.telerik.com)
'Conversion powered by NRefactory.
'Twitter: @telerik
'Facebook: facebook.com/telerik
'=======================================================
```

Your type registration is wrong as well. you have to specify either an interface or an abstract class as dependency and its concrete implementation as its mapping.

e.g
container.RegisterType(Of IContext, Context)()

I don't understand what are trying to achieve by mapping an integer value to car. Do you want  car object to be loaded based on integer value in your parameter?

Comment: Unfortunately i have to use concreate object and don't have a choice.  Above code is just a sample code where in i need to create an object of car and the constructor takes in userid as paramter

Comment: In that case you actually don't need unit over there.. unity (or any DI container for that matter) would be useful where you were having ICar interface and you had multiple implementations of ICar but at that point of time you did not know the actual implementation then you could resolve its type there but surely you can not query using an ID. that is not  how DI works.

Comment: Right i will get the respective project developer to create an interface. So what if there are two constructors one that takes in some int value and other some object how do the specify which one to use for creating instances? container.RegisterType(Of ICar)(New InjectionConstructor(GetType(Integer))) and mark the actual constructor as    <InjectionConstructor()>